# How to create Nexus 4 camera like popup control on a map

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Hi guys I'm trying to create a custom popup control, which would be shown after the user has long-pressed on a Google map. I would like the control to look something like in the nexus' 4 camera application: [see it here.](http://www.google.com/imgres?hl=en&biw=1366&bih=643&tbm=isch&tbnid=XvuZclOsXKvJjM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.lowyat.net/2013/03/01/5603/review-lg-nexus-4-by-google/&docid=9CjMvur2frWt1M&imgurl=http://cdn.lowyat.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/nexus-4-camera-2.jpg&w=602&h=361&ei=qrllUeO2BcrYswa6sID4CA&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:28,s:0,i:175&iact=rc&dur=591&page=2&tbnh=174&tbnw=290&start=17&ndsp=22&tx=136&ty=89)

Can anyone suggest how to start?

I have also searched in the native camera app code found [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_camera/tree/master/src/com/android/camera), but I'm totally lost in all that code. Has someone come across a tutorial of how to build such control? I really googled a lot but couldn't find any solutions.